# Change checkbox state from change event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

When my checkbox is checked, a dialog is opened and when I click cancel, the checkbox should be unchecked.

I can't get this to happen.

The checkbox should be set to its previous state if "no" is selected on the dialog (see the `if` statements).

However, it seems as though setting the model for the checkbox, `$scope.canSupportAccess`, has no effect on the checking of the checkbox inside this function.

I have tested whether or not `$scope.canSupportAccess` is able to update the checkbox at all, by initializing it with `true` and `false`, and can see that it does indeed check or uncheck the checkbox.

I noticed I have to pass in `canSupportAccess` as an argument to the function, because `$scope.canSupportAccess` is not updated inside `updateSupportAccess()` even though `$scope.canSupportAccess` is the model and `updateSupportAccess()` is triggered when the checkbox changes.

Why does `$scope.canSupportAccess` have no effect inside the function, and how can I update the checkbox inside the `updateSupportAccess()` function?

Is this by design, to avoid the `updateSupportAccess()` being called recursively forever?
If so, what is the work around?

Here's my code:

```
export default function (app) {
    app.controller('userDetailCtrl', [
        'shell',
        '$scope',
        function (shell, $scope) {
            $scope.canSupportAccess = false;
            $scope.updateSupportAccess = function (canSupportAccess) {
                if (canSupportAccess) {
                    shell.confirmBox('Allow Access',
                        'Allow access?',
                        'YesNo', true)
                        .result
                        .then(function (result) {
                            if (result === "yes") {
                                $scope.canSupportAccess = true;

                            } else {
                                $scope.canSupportAccess = false;
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    shell.confirmBox('Remove Access',
                        'Revoke access?',
                        'YesNo')
                        .result
                        .then(function (result) {
                            if (result === "yes") {
                                $scope.canSupportAccess = false;
                            } else {
                                $scope.canSupportAccess = true;
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        }]
    );
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       id="supportAccess"
       ng-change="updateSupportAccess(canSupportAccess)"
       ng-model="canSupportAccess" />
<label for="supportAccess">
    Allow access.
</label>
```

Comment: Sounds like there are two different `canSupportAccess` properties that live in different scopes, a really common problem in AngularJS. Try making your property at least one layer separated from `$scope` and not directly attached (e.g. `$scope.access = { canSupport: false }`). Following the ["controller as" syntax best practice](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-view-syntax) reliably avoids this issue. [StackBlitz's AngularJS demo templates](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angularjs) model this convention if you want to play around with it.

Comment: @JacobStamm thanks heaps. That fixed the issue! Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by two different `canSupportAccess` properties that live in different scopes, a really common problem in AngularJS. Try making your property at least one layer separated from $scope and not directly attached (e.g. `$scope.access = { canSupport: false }`). Following the ["controller as" syntax best practice](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-view-syntax) reliably avoids this issue, and for an example of this convention in action where you can play with it, see [StackBlitz's AngularJS demo templates](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angularjs).

See this popular SO answer on the topic of prototypal inheritance in AngularJS for a deep dive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/4028303